# Run module if either cell value of two table ranges change

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to run a module (Currently just a MsgBox for testing) when a cell value changes in two different table ranges.  The ranges are "Table18[Group]" and "Table18[Custom Type]".  These cells will not be targeted themselves but will change based on a targeted cell change in a different column of "Table18", so I believe I need to use intersectRange.

The code doesn't need to follow this structure and if you can think of a better way to do it then I'm happy to start from scratch.  After researching, I'm unable to find a way to set two different ranges.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim intersectRange As Range
    Set intersectRange = Range("Table18[Group]")

    If Not Intersect(Target, intersectRange) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cell has changed."
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

The result here is that nothing happens.  If I change the MsgBox to the Else statement then the MsgBox appears when any cell is changed.

Comment: So, changing a cel **in a different column of "Table18"** should trigger the event. Is that understanding correct? If so, which connection between the two mentioned tables and the above mentioned cells does exist? Is the cel in that "different column" changed manually, or the result of a formula?

Comment: So column 1 will be targeted and the user will select from a list item, column two would be "Table18[Group]" and will change to a value based on the list item selected from column 1.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Not too much sense, related to my above comment... If cells in columns 1 **are manually changed**, this column address should be intersect with `Target`, to make the `Change` event being triggered. If those cells contain formulas and their value is changed by a change in a different place, you should use `Calculate` event (but in a different way). I also asked about the two mentioned tables and their relation with the question. If you only tried confusing us, you can consider it a success. If not, you should clarify what the code should do with their columns values...

Comment: @FaneDuru Why would I come to seek help from the community and try to confuse you?  I find your response slightly condescending if I'm honest.  Hopefully, someone more friendly will come across my question.

Comment: I tried an a little more colored language to emphasize that not clarifying put in discussion issues, even if we asked clarification questions, only confuses as. I did not try offending you but if you feel in such a way I am only sorry. I cannot help without clearly understanding of what you try doing.

Answer (score 0):

`Target` is the cell that has been edited - any other cells that have changed (calculated a different result because of the edit) are not included in `Target`. This is why this code isn't triggering the way you describe you want it to.

To fix this issue you will have to make `intersectRange` a range of all cells that the calculation in `Table18[Group]` is based on.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out how to do it with the following:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Union(Range("Table18[Defined Entity]"), Range("Table18[Custom Type]"))

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        Call TabDisplay
    End If
End Sub
```